# Publish multiple ivy modules at ones dependency issue

Tags: ant, ivy

I'm using ivy to manage a bunch of deb files that depend on one another.  I'm generating ivy files for each deb and adding dependencies where needed.  I'm trying to do a publish but it is requiring me to do a resolve step first.

I'm failing to resolve because none of the modules are in the ivy repo yet.  These are runtime dependencies and I'm using them to be able to pull out of the ivy repo a configuration of deb files.

I tried the example 'multi-project' that comes with the ivy src and found that if you try to publish the 'size' project, it also fails in the same way; I did an `ant clean-all` before to simulate no artifacts/metadata being the repo. I noticed it is using `<ivy:buildlist />` (http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/buildlist.html)

This doesn't seem to work. I use the generated list to execute publishes in order and get the same issue.

Why is my buildlist giving me back the same fileset that is inside it?

```
    <target name="publish-shared" depends="" description="--> Publish project's artifacts to SHARED repository">
            <ivy:buildlist reference="ivy.dep.files">
                    <fileset dir="${ivy.build.dir}" includes="**/ivy.xml"/>
            </ivy:buildlist>
            <for param="ivy.dep.file" list="${toString:ivy.dep.files}" delimiter=":">
                    <sequential>
                            <antcall target="publish-shared-onemod" inheritAll="true" inheritRefs="true">
                                    <param name="ivy.dep.file" value="@{ivy.dep.file}" />
                            </antcall>
                    </sequential>
            </for>
    </target>
    <target name="publish-shared-onemod">
            <ivy:resolve />
            <ivy:publish resolver="shared" artifactspattern="${target.dir}/[artifact].[ext]" status="integration" />
    </target>
```

**Update:**
I had to reverse the buildlist `<ivy:buildlist reference="ivy.dep.files" reverse="true">`
But what is very weird is when I specified a root module (Example:`<ivy:buildlist reference="ivy.dep.files" root="${ivy.module.root}">`) it did not need the reverse. I must be doing something wrong but until I get an error I'm going with reverse.

Comment: Further Info:  I am generating the debian pkgs through a CMake process.  The ivy.xml files are also generated a long side of them.  Because of this I do not have build.xml files for each piece of my project.  I'm hoping to solve this with one ant script at the root of my build dir.

Comment: I tried this and got equivalent output in my echo statements
`<path id="tmp">
                        <fileset dir="${ivy.build.dir}" includes="**/ivy.xml"/>
                </path>
                <ivy:buildlist reference="ivy.dep.files">
                        <fileset dir="${ivy.build.dir}" includes="**/ivy.xml"/>
                </ivy:buildlist>
                <echo>ivy.dep.files=${toString:ivy.dep.files}**************tmp=${toString:tmp}</echo>`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of publishing from the parent build script, why not get each submodule to perform it's own ivy resolve and publish?

The [buildlist](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/buildlist.html) task will determine the correct build order and each submodule will then incrementally build the dependencies of the next:

```
<target name="build-list">
    <ivy:buildlist reference="build-path">
        <fileset dir="." includes="modules/**/build.xml"/>
    </ivy:buildlist>
</target>

<target name="publish" depends="build-list">
    <subant target="publish" buildpathref="build-path" />
</target>
```

Note:

- The [subant](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/subant.html) task is a simpler alternative to the "for" task which is an external dependency on ant-contrib.

Comment: I can't do it the way you suggested because I don't have ant scripts for each module